# How to get substring inside string and store it in another string

Tags: c, string, variables, command-line-arguments

I have two equal strings, I need to delete a portion of one of them, and store it in another.

My code is not working:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *imagetmp = argv[1];
    char *imagefile = imagetmp;
    char *unpackdir = imagetmp;

    // Remove substring from char imagefile
    char * pch;
    pch = strstr (imagefile,".img");
    strncpy (pch,"",6);

    // Print strings
    puts (imagefile);
    puts (unpackdir);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the expected output:

```
./imgtools mysuperimage.img
mysuperimage.img
mysuperimage
```

Here is the actual output:

```
./imgtools mysuperimage.img
mysuperimage
mysuperimage
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The both pointers point to the same string. So changing the string using one pointer gives the same result accessing the string using another pointer. You need to make a copu of the original string if you need to keep two separate strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to make a copy of `argv[1]`, if you have two pointers to the same string they will naturally print the same:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char imagefile[100];
    if(argc < 2) {
       puts("Too few arguments");
       return 1;
    }

    strncpy(imagefile, argv[1], sizeof(imagefile) - 1);
    //char *unpackdir = argv[1]; you can use argv[1] directly

    // Remove substring from char imagefile
    char * pch;
    if((pch = strstr (argv[1],".img")))
        *pch = 0; //or '\0', just null terminate the string, it's simpler 
    else
        puts("Extension not found");

    // Print strings
    puts (imagefile);
    puts (argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @yano, well spotted, thks.

Comment: If the program's 1st argument is longer then 99 characters to program runs into undefined behaviour due to a buffer overflow. Not nice.

Comment: @alk, yes, you are correct, I was thinking the same, corrected it.

Comment: You can't use `strstr` correctly unless you check the return. If there is no `".img"` in `argv[1]`, then `pch == NULL` -- which while `strncpy` should be smart enough to handle the error, but is something best avoided. Simply `if ((pch = strstr (argv[1], ".img")) *pch = 0;` will work, no `strncpy` required. (but the problem with `"20200324.img-event.img"` would remain....)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, yes, good advice, and for total correctness checking the arguments is also advised. I changed the code.

Comment: That's better, good job. Might explain that copying 6-spaces (or empty-string -- whichever it is)  to overwrite the extension probably isn't the best way to go when you can just *nul-terminate* at `pch` with a simple assignment and remove the extension `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, yes definately.